# Could not reach the nested tables textbox using its index

Tags: jquery

I am having a table nested within a parent table. I am inserting rows to that nested table dynamically. I have a text box inside that table. When I click that textbox I go to a sliding window where I pick few data like employee name and append it to the selected textbox. Usually I reach the text box with this code snippet

```
$('#billtable tr:eq('+rowIndex+')').find(".billing_total1").val(tts.toFixed(2));
```

Now I couldnt do this for the nested table. This is my code until now.

This code snippet is for focus action that identifies the current row

```
$('body').on('focus','.start_time4',function()
{
  var indexOfTheChangedRow = $(this).closest("table#packs").find("tr")
                                    .index($(this).closest("tr"));
  console.log("row index p1");

  rowIndexp1 = indexOfTheChangedRow;
});
```

I have a global variable `rowIndexp1` so that I can use it in another function.
This is the code where I get the data to be sent to that text box:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.employeeimages5', function()
    {
     var name = $(this).closest('.customize').find('.firstname').text();
     var name1 = $(this).closest('.customize').find('.pri').text();
     var name2 = $(this).closest('.customize').find('.auto_id').text();
     get_employee1(name, name1, name2, rowIndexp1);

     $(".select_products").hide("slide",{direction:"right"},200);
  });
```

Here I get the employee that is chossen and send the data to another function `get_employee1()`,

```
function get_employee1(val, val1, val2, rowIndexp1)
{
    $("#packageaddtable").closest('table#packs').find('tr:eq(' + rowIndexp1 + ')')
                         .find(".start_time4").val(val);
};
```

Here `start_time4` is the textbox class that I need to append the `val`.
This is my html table structure I have,

```
<div class="packagefortable">
   <table id="packageaddtable">
     <tr>
     <td>
      <div class="package_table">
          <input type="text" class="package_textbox" id="package_textbox_0" 
            name="packname[]" placeholder="Select Package">
          <div class="package_dynamice">
            <table id="packs" class="packs">
              <tr>
               <td>
                   <div class="packcells">
                      <input type="text" class="start_time3" placeholder="Start time">
                      <input type="text" class="start_time4" placeholder="Select Employee">
                   </div>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
      </div>
      </div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Would you mind to remove the horizontal scrollbars from your post?

Comment: Let me get this straight...you are asking how to reach a textbox within a table which is also in a table...without HTML? So you have the full code yet you are having trouble, do you expect us to have an easier time?

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry for it. Please help me code @zer00ne

Comment: Sure, I'll try. Is that JS in order? Is there anything missing or is that the whole code?

Comment: that is the whole code. I have the index of the selected row. I really need to know how to reach that text box by get_employee1() function @zer00ne

Comment: Is `.start_time4` the only one targeted by `get_employee1()`? If so try `$('input:last-of-type').find()`

Comment: No that is not working. The value is placed in some other textbox in my html page @zer00ne

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105680/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-anu).